# How to manipulate xml data in Oracle SOA suite?

Tags: xslt, jdeveloper, bpel, oracle-soa

```
<Employees manager="101" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org" xmlns="http://www.example.org">
            <ns1:person ssn="101">
                <ns1:firstName>Lakshminarayana</ns1:firstName>
                <ns1:lastName>medikoda</ns1:lastName>
            </ns1:person>
            <ns1:person ssn="102">
                <ns1:firstName>narasimha</ns1:firstName>
                <ns1:lastName>mannepalli</ns1:lastName>
            </ns1:person>

            <ns1:person ssn="103">
                <ns1:firstName>venu</ns1:firstName>
                <ns1:lastName>ponakala</ns1:lastName>
            </ns1:person>
</Employees>
```

I want to append new records and remove some records from this file in oracle soa

Comment: Assuming that this is the content of a variable, you will have to use XPath or XSLT in copy operations as usual in BPEL. See [the spec on data handling](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/OS/wsbpel-v2.0-OS.html#_Toc164738494). At what part are you stuck? Can you show how you append / remove records?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using XSLT to make this adjustment, you should be using the BPELX functions in an Assign activity. 
To append a new record into the list you should be doing the following

bpelx:append

The bpelx:append extension in an assign activity enables a BPEL process to append the contents of one variable, expression, or XML fragment to another variable's contents.

```
<bpel:assign> 
   <bpelx:append>
      <bpelx:from ... /> 
      <bpelx:to ... /> 
   </bpelx:append> 
</bpel:assign>
```

The following example will show you how to implement this in your example.

```
<bpel:assign>
    <bpelx:append>
          <from variable="variableFrom" 
                query="variableFromQuery" />
          <to variable="variableTo"
                query="/ns1:Employees/ns1:person" />
    </bpelx:append> 
</bpel:assign>
```

To remove this from the queue you should

The bpelx:remove extension in an assign activity enables a BPEL process to remove a variable.

```
<bpel:assign> 
    <bpelx:remove>
       <bpelx:target variable="variableName" part="Employee" query="query to match node you want to remove" />
    </bpelx:remove> 
</bpel:assign>
```